# Connection to oracle database using connection XML file?

Tags: java, database, windows, oracle

Is there anyone who can tell me how to connect to an oracle database using the XML file with the connection parameters?
Unfortunately, from the file I can recover everything except the password that is encrypted.

Comment: I am not aware of such a file. What system is this for?  Please edit the question and post the xml

Comment: Does the file by any chance come from SQL-Deveoper. I think you can export all connections there as an XML-File. And you can import it there, too.

Comment: Sounds like what you're really asking is how to decrypt an encrypted password.